# List of tuples by taking the same index for an element in haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, refactoring

I have been trying to solve the following problem in haskell:

> Generate a list of tuples (n, s) where 0 ≤ n ≤ 100 and n mod 2 = 0,
> and where s = sum(1..n) The output should be the list
> [(0,0),(2,3),(4,10),...,(100,5050)] [Source](https://dmi.unibas.ch/fileadmin/user_upload/dmi/Studium/Computer_Science/Vorlesungen_FS19/Paradigmen_und_Konzepte_von_Programmiersprachen/exercises/e4/cs109-e4.pdf)

I tried to solve the problem with following code:

```hs
genListTupleSumUntilX :: Int -> [(Int,Int)]
genListTupleSumUntilX x = 
    take x [(n, s) | n <- [1..x], s <- sumUntilN x]
    where
        sumUntilN :: Int -> [Int]
        sumUntilN n 
            | n == 0 = []
            | n == 1 = [1]
            | otherwise = sumUntilN (n-1) ++ [sum[1..n]]
```

However, this code does not give the expected result. (as @Guru Stron Pointed out- Thank you!)

I would also appreciate it if somebody could help me make this code more concise. I am also new to the concept of lazy evaluation, so am unable to determine the runtime complexity. Help will be appreciated.

<strike>However I feel like this code could still be improved upon, espically with:</strike>

1. `take x` in the function seems really inelegant. So **Is there a way to have list comprhensions only map to the same index?**
2. `sumUntilN` feels really verbose. **Is there an *idiomatic* way to do the same in haskell**?

Finally, I am extremely new to haskell and have trouble evaluating the time and space complexity of the function. Can somebody help me there?

Comment: _"I managed to solve the problem with following code:"_ - have you? For me the provided code for `genListTupleSumUntilX 100` gives `[(1,1),(1,3),(1,6),...(1,4950),(1,5050)]` which is clearly not the requested output.

Comment: @GuruStron Oops! Completely overlooked that! Thank you for pointing it out. I will edit my question.

Comment: I have edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sumOfNumsUptoN n = n * (n + 1) `div` 2

genListTupleSumUntilX :: Int -> [(Int, Int)]
genListTupleSumUntilX n = zip [0, 2 .. n] $ map sumOfNumsUptoN [0, 2 .. n]
```

This is of linear complexity on the size of the list.

Comment: Ah! Completely forgot about zip there. The n(n+1)/2 is also a neat trick. Thank you very much. Really appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you overcomplicate things. To produce correct output you can use simple list comprehension:

```hs
genListTupleSumUntilX :: Int -> [(Int,Int)]
genListTupleSumUntilX x = [(n, sum [1..n]) | n <- [0,2..x]]
```

Note that this solution will recalculate the same sums repeatedly (i.e for `n+1` element sum is actually `n + 2 + n + 1 + sumForNthElemnt`, so you can potentially reuse the computation) which will lead to O(n^2) complexity, but for such relatively small `n` it is not a big issue. You can handle this using `scanl` function (though maybe there is more idiomatic approach for memoization):

```hs
genListTupleSumUntilX :: Int -> [(Int,Int)]
genListTupleSumUntilX 0 = []
genListTupleSumUntilX x = scanl (\ (prev, prevSum) curr -> (curr, prevSum + prev + 1 + curr)) (0,0) [2,4..x]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Can you also elaborate on the complexity of this function. I would think sum is an O(n) operation, so the complexity would be O(n^2) but Haskell being a lazily evaulated language, I am completely out of my depth.

Comment: @NaitikMundra yes, second part covers that.

Comment: Yup just saw the edit. Thanks!